# XtraBackup to transfer Server to Server database without creating file

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Using mysqldump, I can sent a whole database from one server to another without creating a temporary file like this

```
mysqldump -u user -p'password' db-name foo | ssh user@remote.box.com mysql -u user -p'password' db-name foo
```

Is there an equivalence using XtraBackup ?

Comment: If this is specific to Galera, please add that as a tag.

Comment: I am comparing to a Galera feature but this is for a standalone database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but the solution would not be as simple compared to using mysqldump/mysql client utilities. You can refer to [wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.1/scripts/wsrep_sst_xtrabackup-v2.sh) script for example commands. In a nutshell, the script does the following :

```
On sender: Take a backup (innobackupex) -> stream (xbstream/tar) -> transfer (socat/nc)
On receiver: Receive the stream -> apply the backup
```

If needed, you can also encrypt the stream.

Comment: Since Galera is using this cleanly when adding a node to a Cluster I through I could easily call a part of the synchronization event outside of a cluster... I'll accept your answer shortly.